# cannot read property of undefined when trying to read from array object

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing an jasmine test in angular 8 and getting error cannot read property of undefined. Its trying to read property of array object. I have tried initialising but it doesn't seem to work.

I am trying to initialise component.myData

Test

```
fit('should update  when acceptSection is called ', () => {
   let updateSpy: jasmine.Spy;
   setupComponent();

   component.myData = [] = ['reviewWindowExpiry'];

   updateSpy = spyOn(component, 'update').withArgs(3).and.returnValue(true);
   component.acceptSection(true);
   expect(updateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Component

```
myData: any;

getNextSectionContent(contentIndex: number) {
    // Get scroll height of agreement
    this.agreementScrollHeight = this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollHeight;

    // Calculate remaining days left on next agreement
    this.hoursUntil = null; // reset this value
    this.daysUntil = differenceInDays(this.myData[contentIndex].reviewWindowExpiry, this.todaysDate);

    if (this.daysUntil < 1) {
      this.hoursUntil = differenceInHours(this.myData[contentIndex].reviewWindowExpiry, this.todaysDate);
      this.daysUntil = null;
    }

    if (this.myData[contentIndex] !== undefined) {
      this.agreementData = this.myData[contentIndex].data;
      this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop -= this.agreementScrollHeight;
    } else {
      this.agreementData = 'NO MORE AGREEMENTS!!';
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have event tried    component.myData = [{'reviewWindowExpiry': Date.UTC}];

Answer (score 0):

You are passing .withArgs(3) to the update function.

Does that set or influence the value of contentIndex? (e.g maybe loops the array 3 times).

As it looks like the array entry is attempting to be retrieved for an index that is not in the array as you only add one item to it.

Does this give you a value?

```
//contentIndex value is 0
this.myData[0].reviewWindowExpiry
```

Also think Date.UTC would return a function, try

```
 component.myData = [{'reviewWindowExpiry': Date.now()}];
```

To get the numeric millisecond value.

Comment: I need to initialise the array to have that property